# Sitemap creators not visiting most pages

Tags: sitemap

I am trying to generate a sitemap for a customers website. When I use the online generators it only ever creates a sitemap with two urls, the index and contact page. Is there something that I have done wrong with my url structure? I can't find anything  obvious.

Comment: What "the" online generator?

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix any [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&ss=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ruralmarketing.co.nz%2F).
2. Use a different/better generator. Don't assume that whatever parser/crawler being used is good enough to deal with bad source code. I've seen at least one dumb enough to go ahead and index a link within a comment. [This one](http://sitemap.im/) seems to return more than whatever you're currently using. That's not an excuse not to fix your code first, anyway. (Also, I have no idea if that's everything, so you'll have to check yourself.)

Comment: Nice sitemap generator.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten to validate the code. I will do that ASAP and then try again. Thanks Su'